# The "no operator" operator, what is it?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

What operator overload would allow me to do this? Is there a "no operator" operator? I understand that to get the value I must do some kind of call(), but I'd like to know if it's possible to clean it up.

```
template<typename T>
class Stuff{
private:
  T stuff{};
public:
  T& operator () (){
  return stuff;
  }
  T& operator = (const T& val){
  stuff = val;
  return stuff;
  }
};

int main()
{
  int myInt = 0;
  Stuff<int> stuff;
  stuff = myInt;
  myInt = stuff(); // <- works
  myInt = stuff; // <- doesn't, is there a way to do it ?
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [user-defined conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)?

Comment: That's not "no operator".    It is a user defined conversion - a member function of `Stuff` named `operator int()` is used to convert a `Stuff` to an `int`.   (Or, since you have a template, an `operator T()` where `T` is the template parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way: build a user-defined conversion function in `Stuff`:

```
operator T() const
{
    std::cout << "I'm here";
    return 0;     
}
```

Because `myInt` is a `T` type, this function will be called in the assignment `myInt = stuff`.

Comment: It's hard to know where to look when you begin coding, thanks a lot !

Comment: If you want to delve deeply into what you can do with operator overloading then look at Boost Spirit.

Comment: @Bathsheba ... and Boost.Spirit will look back.

Comment: that cracked me up

Comment: @ Bathsheba operator T() const {} did the trick ! Thanks again, I spent some hours looking for nothing with all the wrong keywords

Comment: @NickMack: Yes indeed `operator T` is more general - I've amended the answer. Indeed it is hard to search for a technique such as this.